# D3 filtering + transitions = failing

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a time-based visualization that increments up on a unix timestamp, and uses `d3.filter()` to grab the relevant items based on the current timestamp. I can get the filtered data to change color on the map with `.style("fill-color","red")`, but I can't seem to get it to work with `.transition()`. Adding `.transition()` prevents the `.style(...)` from happening. Any ideas what's going on?

```
  d3.json("seattle-buildings-demolished.geojson", function(error, collection) {
    if (error) throw error;
    var transform = d3.geo.transform({point: projectPoint}),
        path = d3.geo.path().projection(transform);

    var feature = g.selectAll("path")
        .data(collection.features)
      .enter().append("path");

    mapDemolitions.on("viewreset", reset);
    reset();

    // Reposition the SVG to cover the features.
    function reset() {
      var bounds = path.bounds(collection),
          topLeft = bounds[0],
          bottomRight = bounds[1];

      svg .attr("width", bottomRight[0] - topLeft[0])
          .attr("height", bottomRight[1] - topLeft[1])
          .style("left", topLeft[0] + "px")
          .style("top", topLeft[1] + "px");

      g   .attr("transform", "translate(" + -topLeft[0] + "," + -topLeft[1] + ")");

      feature.attr("d", path);
    }

    // Use Leaflet to implement a D3 geometric transformation.
    function projectPoint(x, y) {
      var point = mapDemolitions.latLngToLayerPoint(new L.LatLng(y, x));
      this.stream.point(point.x, point.y);
    }

    var time = 1262332800;
    var previousTime;
    var filtered = collection.features.filter(function(d){
      return (d.properties.UnixIssue < 1262332800);
    });

    function update() {
      previousTime = time;
      time = time + 623328;

      filtered = feature.filter(function(d){ return (d.properties.UnixIssue < time);}).transition().duration(500).style("fill-color","red");
      console.log(time);
      console.log(filtered);
      setTimeout(update,100);      
     }
    update();
  });

 });
```

Comment: There is no fill-color only fill-opacity. You need to use fill.

Comment: [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/styling.html#SVGStylingProperties) is the knowledge source.

Comment: Thanks - I made that change, but still no dice.

Comment: Try increasing the timeout value. By starting a transition, you're cancelling any that are running, so you could be overwriting the transitions before you see what's happening.

Comment: Unfortunately your question is not complete enough to help further.  It would be better if your code was a working example. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/CoolBlue/xmrwjhdo/3/) is an example of the principle which works fine.

Comment: Thanks Lars - that was a good idea. Still no luck though - I even pulled the incrementing out and just ran the d3 code on initial page load, and the transition doesn't work there either. 

I'm wondering if there's something going on with what I'm trying to transition: eg trying to do a transition on a filtered selection. Does that even make sense as a direction to pursue? Should I try doing the transition on each element of the selection array in a forEach loop or something?